# How to refer to parent class of base class from sub-sub-base-class static method without specifying base class name

Tags: php, subclass, static-methods, superclass, base-class

In PHP, I want to call a static method in the parent of the parent class from the sub-sub-class, without referring to the parent class of the parent class's name (please see the comment in the code below):

```
class Base {

  public static function helloStatic() {

    return "Hello base!\n";

  }

}

class Foo extends Base {

  private $fooMember;

  public static function helloStatic() {

    return "Hello foo!\n";

  }

  private function __construct() {

    $this->fooMember = "hello";

  }

  public function getFooMember() {

    return $this->fooMember;

  }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

  private $barMember;

  public static function helloStatic() {

    // I want to write the equivalent of:
    //echo Base::helloStatic();
    // here *without specifying any class names*

    echo get_parent_class(get_parent_class())::helloStatic();

  }

}

echo Bar::helloStatic();
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Hello base!
```

OUTPUT:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting ',' or ';' on line <b>45</b><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the parent class name inside a variable and use that variable to call the static method. Like this:

```
$parentClassName = get_parent_class(get_parent_class());
echo $parentClassName::helloStatic();
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Please let me know if you also happen to know of a one-liner solution. Thanks.